# Parsing the String to different format in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text document and I need to add two @ symbols before the keywords present in an array.

**Sample text and Array:**

```
str ="This is a sample text document which consists of all demographic information of employee here is the value you may need,name: George employee_id:14296blood_group:b positive this is the blood group of the employeeage:32"

arr=['name','employee_id','blood_group','age']
```

**Required Text:**

```
str ="This is a sample text document which consists of all demographic information of employee here is the value you may need, @@name: George @@employee_id:14296 @@blood_group:b positive this is the blood group of the employee @@age:32"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `replace` function

```
str ="This is a sample text document which consists of all demographic information of employee here is the value you may need,name: George employee_id:14296blood_group:b positive this is the blood group of the employeeage:32"
arr = ['name','employee_id','blood_group','age']

for w in arr:
    str = str.replace(w, f'@@{w}')
print(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop over arr and use the str.replace function:

```
for repl in arr:
    strng.replace(repl, '@@'+repl)
    
print(strng)
```

However, I urge you to change the variable name `str` because it is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the value and add space and double @@ before the replaced value and in the result replace double spaces with one space.

```
str ="This is a sample text document which consists of all demographic information of employee here is the value you may need,name: George employee_id:14296blood_group:b positive this is the blood group of the employeeage:32"
arr=['name','employee_id','blood_group','age']

for i in arr:
    str = str.replace(i, " @@{}".format(i))
print(str.replace("  ", " "))
```

Output

```
This is a sample text document which consists of all demographic information of employee here is the value you may need, @@name: George  @@employee_id:14296 @@blood_group:b positive this is the blood group of the employee @@age:32
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use `re` module for that task following way

```
import re
txt = "This is a sample text document which consists of all demographic information of employee here is the value you may need,name: George employee_id:14296blood_group:b positive this is the blood group of the employeeage:32"
arr=['name','employee_id','blood_group','age']
newtxt = re.sub('('+'|'.join(arr)+')',r'@@\1',txt)
print(newtxt)
```

Output:

```
This is a sample text document which consists of all demographic information of employee here is the value you may need,@@name: George @@employee_id:14296@@blood_group:b positive this is the blood group of the employee@@age:32
```

Explanation: here I used regular expression to catch words from your list and replace each with @@word. This is single pass, as opposed to X passes when using multiple str.replace (where X is length of `arr`), so should be more efficient for cases where `arr` is long.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can convert the below in a loop for lengthier list. There seems to be space before @@ too.

`str= str[:str.find(arr[0])] + ' @@' + str[str.find(arr[0]):]`

`str= str[:str.find(arr[1])] + ' @@' + str[str.find(arr[1]):]`

`str= str[:str.find(arr[2])] + ' @@' + str[str.find(arr[2]):]`

`str= str[:str.find(arr[3])] + ' @@' + str[str.find(arr[3]):]`